# Qual é a diferença entre sublime_plugin.TextCommand e sublime_plugin.WindowComand?

Tags: python, sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Quando vamos criar um plugin, geralmente o Sublime Text cria uma amostra usando a classe `sublime_plugin.TextCommand`.

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin


class ExampleCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        self.view.insert(edit, 0, "Hello, World!")
```

Mas vi também que temos a classe `sublime_plugin.WindowCommand`.

Eu gostaria de saber qual é a diferença entre `TextCommand` e `WindowCommand`. Pra que cada uma delas serve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os WindowCommands não requerem uma view para serem executados, embora possa existir uma view associada.

Pelo contrário, os TextCommands requerem uma view para estarem disponíveis.

A titulo de exemplo, no exemplo que forneceu:

```
self.view.insert(edit, 0, "Hello, World!")
```

A view é componente obrigatória por ser um TextCommand.

No exemplo abaixo de WindowCommand não é utilizada uma view mas apenas o acesso a window do sublime para criar um novo documento.

Ref.: Extracto do plugin side_bar
(http://folk.uib.no/hab001/Info100/Sublime%20Text%202.0.2/Data/Packages/Default/side_bar.py)

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin
import os

class NewFileAtCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):

def run(self, dirs):
    v = self.window.new_file()
    if len(dirs) == 1:
        v.settings().set('default_dir', dirs[0])

def is_visible(self, dirs):
    return len(dirs) == 1
```

> **Window Commands**
>
> Window commands operate at the window level. This doesn’t mean that you 
>   can’t manipulate views from window commands, but rather that you don’t 
>   need views in order for window commands to be available. For instance, 
>   the built-in command new_file is defined as a WindowCommand so it works 
>   even when no view is open. Requiring a view to exist in that case 
>   wouldn’t make sense.
>
> Window command instances have a .window attribute to point to the window 
>   instance that created them.
>
> The .run() method of a window command doesn’t require any positional 
>   parameter.
>
> Window commands are able to route text commands to their window’s active 
>   view.
>
> **Text Commands**
>
> Text commands operate at the view level, so they require a view to exist 
>   in order to be available.
>
> Text command instances have a .view attribute pointing to the view 
>   instance that created them.
>
> The .run() method of text commands requires an edit instance as its 
>   first positional argument.

Referências:

http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/plugins.html#window-commands

http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/plugins.html#text-commands